# How to change column values based on date using a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger that will change the value in column "RateID" when a record reaches a specified end date in column "EndDate".

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_tblContractExtension_RateChange
ON [dbo].[AgreementExtensionHistory]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
   UPDATE AgreementExtensionHistory
   SET RateID = 114
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE i.EndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

GO
```

Again I want the RateID to default to the value of '114' when the end date in the enddate column is reached.

Comment: What's wrong with your trigger?

Comment: It is not returning the RateID value 114 when the end date is reached.

Comment: Why you need INSERTED here, just update your table `WHERE AgreementExtensionHistory.EndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: INSERTED was added from the various attempts I've made trying to figure this out. Also, I have tried your method before and it does not work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Usually in a trigger you would join inserted and AgreementExtensionHistory so it would update ONLY those rows.

Comment: @SeanLange True, but in this case I think it doesn't metter, all what you need is the condition _where datecolumn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_. Something missing here.

Comment: @Sami not quite. IF the value for datecolumn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP it will update the entire table.

Comment: A record does not "reach a specified end date" just because time passes and the current date reaches or passes this end date. If you are expecting this (or any) trigger to execute simply based on the passage of time, you have chosen the wrong path.

Comment: I am not expecting that at all. I am new to programming, and I can't quite word things the way others expect on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to include AgreementExtensionHistory in your update or it will update the entire table.

Something like this is likely what you are after.

```
UPDATE aeh
SET RateID = 114
FROM Inserted i
join AgreementExtensionHistory aeh on aeh.YourKeyColumn = i.YourKeyColumn
--WHERE i.EndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE datediff(MILLISECOND, i.EndDate, Current_Timestamp) < 500 --within 1/2 second
```

Yes the problem is your trigger is using the current_timestamp as a join predicate. Your code is assuming the time value will be the same in the trigger as the insert. This is not the case because the insert and the trigger are separate objects. They each get their own value for current_timestamp and will never be identical.

This is easy to prove with a simple table and trigger.

```
create table TriggerTest(SomeCol varchar(10), SomeDate datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

GO

create Trigger trTriggerTest on TriggerTest AFTER insert
AS
    select *
        , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    from inserted

GO

insert TriggerTest(SomeCol) select 'test'
```

--EDIT--
LOL. After some more testing it seems that sometimes the date values are identical and other times not making this even more of a brittle approach.

Comment: The column value is not updated even without a join(see previous comments)

Comment: My guess is the where predicate is causing the issue.

Comment: Tried this just no, but no luck. Definitely missing something here.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't know, seems like _EndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ is always False, so the join wont makes any changes here since the value is not updated anyway. which mean (at the very least) the OP does not provies all the desired info.

Comment: And if the predicate was able to get a match it would update the entire table because the original query did not specify which rows in the table to update, so it would update all of them.

Comment: @Moodsy What is the datatype of _EndDate_ column?

Comment: That would be "Datetime"

Comment: Maybe you should just change the where predicate to look at datediff and have tolerance of maybe 1 second or something along those lines. But keep the join unless you want to update the entire table, not just the currently affected row(s).

Comment: @Moodsy - A change to the where predicate would make this work better. See my edit.

Comment: I have tried these suggestions, but no luck. However, they are very helpful and it only gives me more ideas on ways to figure this out. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Perhaps if you could share the table design, some sample data, the desired results, what you tried and what happened we can help. Just saying "this doesn't work" is not very useful. But glad my efforts offered you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_tblContractExtension_RateChange
ON [dbo].[AgreementExtensionHistory]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
AS
   INSERT INTO AgreementExtensionHistory (<Columns Here>)
   SELECT <Columns Here> --instead of RateID  column use CASE expression
          CASE WHEN EndDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 114
               ELSE RateID END
   FROM INSERTED;
GO
```

I suggest to add at least 2 seconds to the EndDate as

```
CASE WHEN DATEADD(Second, 2,EndDate) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 114
     ELSE RateID END
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Second, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, EndDate) <= 5 --within 5 seconds
     THEN 114
     ELSE RateID END
```

Comment: Not sure this is what they want. In an update if the timestamp matched it would insert a second row. And this still has the issue of timestamp variance between the insert statement and the trigger.

Comment: Yeah, still thinking about it

Comment: @SeanLange [LOL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3610ec1bf0d0aa28689f1fa21d379f19)